# Error during Travis-CI build with gradle and LibGDX

Tags: gradle, libgdx, travis-ci

I am trying to use Travis-CI with gradle to automatically build a LibGDX project. When `./gradle assemble` is run, it throws and error that is, 
`Cannot find symbol 
new LwjglApplication(new MainCoreClass(), config);` 
It looks like a classpath problem but it isnt working.

Comment: Did you add it as a dependency? Can you paste you build file? Also it should be running `./gradlew assemble`

Comment: @SageSmith I made it run ./gradlew assemble and it still failed. Here is the build file: http://pastebin.com/LptXESJq